# Discord.js and cpanel lose connexion problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

Hello i have host one bot on cpanel.

I go my terminal and start my bot like this : **node index.js**

But after ~ 30 minutes my session expire and i need restart discord bot server.

If i close close terminal page it close my bot.

Please how to make with cpanel for stay discord bot online 24/24 - 7/7

Ty